# `scatterplot3d`: can not add a regression plane to 3D scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have created a 3d Scatterplot in R and want to add a regression plane. I have looked at code from the statmethods.net website, which can be very useful, and it worked. I then tried it with my own data and the plane did not show up.

```
library(scatterplot3d)
s3d <- scatterplot3d(Try$Visits, Try$Net.Spend, Try$Radio, pch=16, highlight.3d = TRUE, type = "h", main = "3D Scatterplot")
fit <- lm(Try$Visits ~ Try$Net.Spend +Try$Radio)
s3d$plane3d(fit)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce the issue with the following reproducible example:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(20)
y <- runif(20)
z <- 0.1 + 0.3 * x + 0.5 * y + rnorm(20, sd = 0.1)
dat <- data.frame(x, y, z)
rm(x,y,z)

fit <- lm(z ~ x + y, data = dat)
library(scatterplot3d)
s3d <- scatterplot3d(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z, pch=16, highlight.3d = TRUE, type = "h", main = "3D Scatterplot")
s3d$plane3d(fit)
```

[image]

You should avoid `$` in model formula. Use `data` argument instead:

```
fit <- lm(Visits ~ Net.Spend + Radio, data = Try)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your z-variable(dependent variable) in the scatter plot is Try$Radio whereas in the regression model, the dependent variable is Try$Visits and this is causing confusion. The 3rd variable in the scatter plot argument is treated as the dependent variable R.